# Asignación de variables char* de un arreglo

Tags: array, c, string, lista

intento definir un arreglo de caracteres definido de esta manera:

```
char *lista[cantidad];
```

Donde "cantidad" está definida previamente. Intento rellenar este arreglo con la palabra "perro", mediante el siguiente ciclo iterativo:

```
    char *animal = "perro";
    for(int k = 0; k < cantidad; k++){
        strcpy(lista[k], animal);
    }
```

Sin embargo, el programa al ejecutarlo (compila bien), se detiene al momento de llegar al ciclo que he adjuntado. No se a que se debe el problema, las librerías están agregadas. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿En algún momento haces un **alloc* a "lista"? Haz el favor de poner un [mcve] para que no tengamos que adivinar cuáles son las líneas de tu programa que faltan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que el problema está en:

```
char *lista[cantidad];
```

> intento definir un arreglo de caracteres definido de esta manera

No estás haciendo un arreglo de caracteres, estás haciendo una arreglo de punteros a caracteres, **sin inicializar** los array de caracteres en donde vas a guardar los elementos de la lista, esto genera que la función `strcpy()` trabaje sobre direcciones en memoria que tienen basura porque no se inicializaron de la manera correcta, esto puede hacer que trate de acceder a espacios en memoria que no existen o generar otros problemas por tratar de interpretar cómo y dónde está guardada la string.

Te recomiendo asignar el espacio para la lista que vas a hacer, en este caso podría ser un array de dos dimensiones en la cual se tenga una lista de X número de palabras, cada una con Y número de letras, así:

```
#define CANTIDAD 3
#define CANTIDAD_LETRAS 20

char lista[CANTIDAD][CANTIDAD_LETRAS];

int main()
{
    char *animal = "perro";
    
    for(int k = 0; k < CANTIDAD; k++){
        strcpy(lista[k], animal);
    }
    
    for(int k = 0; k < CANTIDAD; k++){
        printf("%s\n",lista[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Creo que la confusión viene de la sintaxis para definir una string de esta manera:

```
char *animal = "perro";
```

Cuando haces esto lo que pasa se crea una variable anónima constante que tiene como contenido:

```
['p','e','r','r','o','\0']
```

Ese último carácter es para indicar que la string terminó, funciones como `strcpy()` utilizan este carácter para interpretar dónde termina la string. Luego de crear esta variable se guarda la dirección de la variable anónima en el puntero `char * animal`. **La diferencia acá es que reservamos el espació para la string con el formato correcto**.

Si quisieras hacer algo similar con el código que provees (lo cuál no considero adecuado, a menos que la lista fuese constante), podrías hacer algo así para inicializar las strings (insisto, si esta lista fuese constante):

```
char *lista[]={"perro","gato","ardilla"};

int main()
{
    
   for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++){
        printf("%s\n",lista[k]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```