# Inicializar un array de caracteres

Tags: c, string, lista, archivo

intento leer unos datos desde un archivo .txt, los cuales se encuentran dispuestos de la siguiente manera:

```
3
auto
auto
bicicleta
bicicleta
bicicleta
barco
barco
```

En la primera línea, se define la cantidad de transportes. En las siguientes líneas se encuentran los datos, los cuales pueden estar repetidos o no. Necesito almacenar estos datos en una lista, para que me queden de tal manera:

```
[auto,bicicleta,barco]
```

Para esto debo verificar que el dato no se repita dentro de la lista, pero no es ese el problema. El problema que tengo, es como definir e inicializar una variable que inicialmente no contenga dato alguno, y que posteriormente me permita almacenar los datos. Suponiendo que n = cantidad de transportes, he probado las siguientes opciones, las cuales no consiguen solucionar mi problema:

```
1. char *lista[n];
2. char **lista = (char**)malloc(n*sizeof(char*));
```

Al probar las opciones mostradas, se sobrescribe el dato en la primera posición, o simplemente se detiene la ejecución del programa ya compilado. Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: El array bidimensional que te puse como respuesta en la [otra pregunta tuya](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/421035/asignaci%c3%b3n-de-variables-char-de-un-arreglo) es una buena solución. Por cierto, toda variable que inicialices tiene datos, sean basura, sea un valor de cero, cualquier dato... Pero toda variable tiene un valor cuando la defines.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la repuesta y aclaración del concepto, una última consulta, si la cantidad de letras puede variar según la palabra y defino, por ejemplo CANTIDAD_LETRAS=15 ¿habrá algún problema, sabiendo que ninguna palabra excederá esa cantidad de letras?

Comment: Sí, vas a tener problemas, de hecho si usas el array bidimensional y la palabra es más grande lo que va a hacer es ocupar el espacio del elemento del array que sigue. Puedes usar `strnpcy` para copiar una cantidad definida de caracteres (ten en cuenta el carácter `'\0'` ), si bien esto mantiene la integridad de tus otros elementos cortaría tu string sobredimensionada para que cumpla con el máximo número de caracteres. También puedes intentar usar memoria asignada de manera dinámica para guardar strings de diferentes tamaños.